# Differentiate complex function with absolute values

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives

I have the following function:
$$\frac{d}{dt}\left(A(z,t)\cdot|A(z,t)|^2\right)$$
I know that the function $A$ is a complex function with $z$ as complex value and $t$ as time input. When I want to differentiate them, what should I consider (main problem here is the absolute value of $A$)? Can I simply move the differentiation into the absolute, e.g. having something like
$$=A'\cdot|A|^2+A\cdot\left(2\cdot|A|\cdot|A'|\right)$$?
Or should I use another approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $|A(z,t)|^2 = A(z,t)\overline{A(z,t)}$, you can use the product rule to compute

$$\frac{d}{dt}\left(A(z,t)|A(z,t)|^2\right) = \frac{d}{dt}\left(A(z,t)^2\overline{A(z,t)}\right) = 2A(z,t)A_t(z,t)\overline{A(z,t)} + A(z,t)^2\overline{A_t(z,t)},$$

which is

$$2|A(z,t)|^2A_t(z,t) + A(z,t)^2\overline{A_t(z,t)}.$$

Comment: I can not see any derived version of A, did I make a mistake?

Comment: I use $A_t$ to mean the time derivative of $A$.

Comment: Ah, ok, I was already wondering. Thanks!